# Inconsistent android sqlite database check

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to check if an entry in an sqlite android database exists. My code works when the Id's are unique but when there are duplicate Ids with different `suspensionUnit` values, things are inconsistent. On the first try my code returns false regardless of whats in the db i.e. even when it should return true it always returns false the first time. Trying again, however returns true and continues to return true so long as I am in the same fragment. Now, if I try checking for another entry with the same Id but different `suspensionUnit` I will get false on the first attempt and then true again and again. If I now try the first entry (the one we started with) it goes back to false again. ARGH

```
public Boolean getGear(String id, String suspensionUnit) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String Query = "Select * from " + TABLE_GEAR
                + " where " + KEY_GEAR_ID + " = \"" + id
                + "\" and " + KEY_SUSPENSION_UNIT + " = \"" + suspensionUnit + "\";";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: There is some problem with the values in the database, or with the values of the two parameters. Neither of which you have shown.

Comment: @CL.Thanks for the note, the problem was indeed with another part of the code which I was able to determine after looking at the data in the database rather than trying to look at my code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error in another part of my code where I was erroneously updating everything in the table. doh